# How to run os command `echo` with `-n` parameter in Python

Tags: python

I have below code in python3:

```py
>>> os.system('echo -n abc')
-n abc
0
```

the output has `-n` which is not correct. If I run the command on terminal it doesn't print the newline at the end. It seems `os.system` method doesn't understand `-n` parameter. How can I solve this issue?

I have tried subprocess module but got the same result:

```py
>>> subprocess.call('echo -n abc', shell=True)
-n abc
0
```

Comment: Use the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system) module instead.

Comment: `os.system()` will run the command in a shell it forks. E.g. on my system that would be: `/bin/sh -c "echo -n abc"` which would yield the results you're expecting. Your shell and the `echo` it uses likely does not understand the `-n` argument. Needless to say this would be somewhat unusual (convoluted) way to print anything from Python.

Comment: I have tried `/bin/sh -c "echo -n abc"` gives me the same result.

Comment: `subprocess` doesn't work as well. I have posted the output

Comment: On my Ubuntu machine running `python3 -c "import os; os.system('echo -n abc')"` works fine

Answer (score 1):

#### Is this correct behavior for `echo` to have?

**This is legal, standards-compliant behavior for an `echo` implementation to have.** Quoting from [the POSIX `echo` standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) (the APPLICATION USAGE section of which is also strongly recommended reading):

> If the first operand is `-n`, or if any of the operands contain a backslash character, the results are implementation-defined.

Thus, `echo` is *allowed* to print `-n` literally -- *or to do anything else when it's given as the first operand*.

---

#### Why does my interactive shell do something different?

As the above-quoted specification says, behavior is undefined when `-n` is given as first argument. This means *every* behavior is equally legal; so not printing a trailing newline is *also* a legal behavior. Presumably your interactive shell does that (on the system at hand), whereas your `/bin/sh` does not.

---

#### How can I get reliable behavior when starting a shell to print text without a trailing newline?

If you want a command with well-specified behavior, use `printf` instead:

```
os.system('printf %s abc')
```

...will always print the exact string `abc` with no trailing newline, with any POSIX-compliant `/bin/sh`.

<sub>But of course, don't do any of this in Python; `sys.stdout.write('abc')` is far more sensible.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. I tried `os.system('printf %s abc')` doesn't print newline at the end but it prints a 0. I think the 0 is the command exit code. How can I get rid of that? I will need to read the output.

Comment: The `0` is not printed by `printf`, it's the return value from `os.system`; it's printed by the Python interpreter when the command in question is run at a REPL.

Comment: If you change your Python code to, say, `retval = os.system('printf %s abc')`, then the `0` will be stored in `retval` instead of printed.

Comment: As for reading the output into a Python variable, `os.system()` doesn't let you do that at all. Use the `subprocess` module instead.

Comment: I have added `subprocess` output in my question. I got the same output as `system`. Did I use it in a wrong way?

Comment: This is a well-written, good answer that I don't like. +1